# Disable special characters on long press (ApplePressAndHoldEnabled) ONLY within Terminal Version 2.12.7 (445)

Tags: terminal, keyboard

- macOS version 12.6
- Terminal Version 2.12.7 (445)

Before my last macOS update today, I was able to speed page in `less` by holding <kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>K</kbd>. While outside the terminal I was able to use the suggested keys from other languages upon press-and-hold.

As I am working in 3 different human languages, I would like to keep the `ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true` (enabled) for all apps **except** when using the terminal.

Looking in forums and on SE I can only find the option to globally disable via:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false;
```

Can anyone provide me with settings to disable `ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` for the **terminal only**?

Comment: You have to use its own domain name - there's a full explanation on Stack Overflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152551/how-can-i-disable-applepressandholdenabled-for-a-specific-application-repeat

Comment: `defaults write com.apple.Terminal ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false` did it for me thx